# Pulling every href from a ul using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get every link from an unordered list using python. How would I go about pulling the href link from every list element (i.e pulling href = "al/bessemer/4921-promenade-parkway")?

```
uri = 'https://locations.fivebelow.com/al'
html = urlopen(uri)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
soup.find_all('ul', class_ = 'Directory-listLinks')
```

And returns this

```
[<ul class="Directory-listLinks"><li class="Directory-listItem"><a class="Directory-listLink" data-count="(1)" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="al/bessemer/4921-promenade-parkway"><span class="Directory-listLinkText">Bessemer</span></a></li><li class="Directory-listItem"><a class="Directory-listLink" data-count="(3)" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="al/birmingham"><span class="Directory-listLinkText">Birmingham</span></a></li><li class="Directory-listItem"><a class="Directory-listLink" data-count="(1)" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="al/cullman/1230-cullman-shopping-ctr-nw"><span class="Directory-listLinkText">Cullman</span></a></li><li class="Directory-listItem"><a class="Directory-listLink" data-count="(1)" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="al/daphne/6850-13-highway-90"><span class="Directory-listLinkText">Daphne</span></a></li><li class="Directory-listItem"><a class="Directory-listLink" data-count="(1)" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="al/decatur/1241-pointe-mallard-parkway"><span class="Directory-listLinkText">Decatur</span></a></li><li class="Directory-listItem"><a class="Directory-listLink" data-count="(1)" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="al/dothan/3500-ross-clark-cir"><span class="Directory-listLinkText">Dothan</span></a></li><li class="Directory-listItem"><a class="Directory-listLink" data-count="(1)" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="al/florence/390-cox-creek-parkway"><span class="Directory-listLinkText">Florence</span></a></li><li class="Directory-listItem"><a class="Directory-listLink" data-count="(1)" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="al/foley/2528-s-mckenzie-street"><span class="Directory-listLinkText">Foley</span></a></li><li class="Directory-listItem"><a class="Directory-listLink" data-count="(1)" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="al/fultondale/3453-lowery-parkway"><span class="Directory-listLinkText">Fultondale</span></a></li><li class="Directory-listItem"><a class="Directory-listLink" data-count="(1)" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="al/gadsden/526-meighan-blvd-east"><span class="Directory-listLinkText">Gadsden</span></a></li><li class="Directory-listItem"><a class="Directory-listLink" data-count="(2)" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="al/huntsville"><span class="Directory-listLinkText">Huntsville</span></a></li><li class="Directory-listItem"><a class="Directory-listLink" data-count="(1)" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="al/montgomery/7670-east-chase-parkway"><span class="Directory-listLinkText">Montgomery</span></a></li><li class="Directory-listItem"><a class="Directory-listLink" data-count="(1)" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="al/oxford/50-commons-way"><span class="Directory-listLinkText">Oxford</span></a></li><li class="Directory-listItem"><a class="Directory-listLink" data-count="(1)" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="al/prattville/1472-cotton-exchange"><span class="Directory-listLinkText">Prattville</span></a></li><li class="Directory-listItem"><a class="Directory-listLink" data-count="(1)" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="al/tuscaloosa/1451-dr-edward-hillard-drive"><span class="Directory-listLinkText">Tuscaloosa</span></a></li></ul>]
```

It returns a list with one element with everything in one index. I was wondering how I could get it to create separate list entries for each list item, and then pull the href links from them.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the error you are fronting?

Comment: first check if page doesn't use JavaScript to add elements - `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript. Later use `find_all` to get all `<li>` or all `<a>` and later uses `for`-loop to get href from every `<a>` separatelly.

Comment: always put code, data and error messagea as text in question, not images. And always show your code.

Comment: Show a [mcve] of your current attempt, so that people would understand what you are trying to do, reproduce your problem, and then help you solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Try SimplifiedDoc's solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy.request import req
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
uri = 'https://locations.fivebelow.com/al'
html = req.get(uri)
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
lstA = doc.getElementByClass('Directory-listLinks').listA(url=uri)
print ([a.url for a in lstA])
```

Result:

```
[u'https://locations.fivebelow.com/al/foley/2528-s-mckenzie-street', u'https://locations.fivebelow.com/al/oxford/50-commons-way', u'https://locations.fivebelow.com/al/decatur/1241-pointe-mallard-parkway', u'https://locations.fivebelow.com/al/prattville/1472-cotton-exchange', u'https://locations.fivebelow.com/al/bessemer/4921-promenade-parkway', u'https://locations.fivebelow.com/al/tuscaloosa/1451-dr-edward-hillard-drive', u'https://locations.fivebelow.com/al/daphne/6850-13-highway-90', u'https://locations.fivebelow.com/al/fultondale/3453-lowery-parkway', u'https://locations.fivebelow.com/al/dothan/3500-ross-clark-cir', u'https://locations.fivebelow.com/al/montgomery/7670-east-chase-parkway', u'https://locations.fivebelow.com/al/huntsville', u'https://locations.fivebelow.com/al/birmingham', u'https://locations.fivebelow.com/al/florence/390-cox-creek-parkway', u'https://locations.fivebelow.com/al/cullman/1230-cullman-shopping-ctr-nw', u'https://locations.fivebelow.com/al/gadsden/526-meighan-blvd-east']
```